# Count MySql database rows with field value = '1'

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to count the number of rows in my database with the field 'Level' equal to '1'. I already have this set up to count the fields, see code below.

```
$result = mysql_query("select count(1) FROM username");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$total = $row[0];
```

Now I would like to adapt this to only select field where the Level = 1 in the database.

I already have the database connection setup and its working fine.

**I did try this code but was gettign nowhere.**

```
$admins = mysql_query("select count(1) FROM WHERE Level='1'");
$totaladmins = mysql_fetch_array($admins);
$totaladmins = $admins[0];
```

Once the number of rows have been calculated it is displayed to the users through the following code

```
<h4><?php echo $total?> Users registered</h4>
```

**Any help is supper appreciated.**

Comment: select count(*) from username where level=1  ... or '1'  .... i see no schema

Comment: First try to construct queries against MySQL directly. Fix the errors. And it actually says "there were errors", *if* you checked for them. Now would be a good to stop using the obsoleted `mysql_` functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There problem you're having is just because you forgot to include which table to select from. Instead of:

```
SELECT count(1) FROM WHERE Level='1';
```

Your query should be:

```
SELECT count(1) FROM username WHERE Level='1';
```

Hopefully this fixes your problem. :)

Comment: Thanks, perfect fixed it. ill mark it as the answer in 7 minutes when i'm, allowed to :D

Comment: Im glad you did, been trying this for ages. its way too late some rest would help, but I needed to get it fixed tonight, thanks ever so much.